# Link to latest post on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

From the Tumblr [customization docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) you can grab the `{Permalink}` of the current page using the shortcode just shown.

Is there a shortcode to retrieve the most recent post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's not in the customization docs, it can't exist. However, there's a simple workaround. First, you need to "burn" your RSS feed with [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.com) and then enable the feature [BuzzBoost](http://support.google.com/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78976&topic=13240&ctx=topic) in Publicize tools setting it to display just the latest item from the feed.